# How to get the result when calling Ajax function

Tags: ruby-on-rails

> I need to get the email-id of the client when im clicking the person
>   name if his email-is is exist in db means by default it should need to
>   show

```
$("#user_employee_id").change(function(){
  alert(1);
    var user_id = $(this).val(); 
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "/users/emailcheck",
      data: { id: user_id }
   }).success(function(res){
    console.log(res);
     $("#user_email").val(res.data["user"]["email"]);
   });
  });
```

controller.rb

```
def emailcheck
 @user = User.find_by(id: params[:id])
 if @user.present? 
    render :json => {:user => @user.to_json(:only => [:email]) }
 end  
end
```

> After doing this also im not getting email can any one suggest me im
>   wrong, i need tan email-id when im clicking the person, i have 1400
>   data every one is having email-id please help me out how to get
>   corresponding employee name when im clicking i need to get thier mail
>   id bydefalut in mail-id textbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the line in ajax

```
$("#user_email").val(res.data["user"]["email"]);
```

With

```
$("#user_email").val(res.email);
```

And in controller:

```
def emailcheck
  @user = User.find_by(id: params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.present? 
      format.json { render json: {:email => @user.email} }
    else
      format.json { render json: {:email => " "} }
    end
  end  
end
```